# Does a functor always return a lifted type in haskell when the fmap transformation is applied?

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory, lifting

Let's say I have an `Int` and I apply `fmap` transformation using the `Maybe` as a functor, I get a wrapped type, i.e., `Maybe Int`. So can I consider this as lifting? If so does a functor always return a lifted type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fmap` always takes a function of type `a -> b`, and gives you a function of type `f a -> f b`, for some type constructor `f`. So if you call the application of the type constructor `f` to the type `a` "lifting", then yes, `fmap` always gives you a function that works on "lifted types".<sup>1</sup>

The builtin Haskell type class `Functor` has as members type constructors of kind `* -> *`: things that can be applied to any type you like, to produce a new type (like `Maybe` in your example). In category theory terms, the type constructor itself (e.g. `Maybe`) represents the mapping from objects of the source category to the target category, and `fmap` provides the mapping of morphisms (remembering that the **Hask** catogory has Haskell types as objects and Haskell functions as morphisms).

So Haskell `Functor` can only represent endofunctors on the category **Hask**, since maps Haskell types & functions to Haskell types & functions. But it can't even represent any possible endofunctor, since we can't use it to map objects (types) arbitrarily. My Haskell functor can't map `Int` to `Maybe String` and `Char` to `Bool`, it *must* map each type to "the same type" under a type constructor (as `Maybe` maps `Int` to `Maybe Int`, `Char` to `Maybe Char`, `Maybe (Maybe (Maybe Bool))` to `Maybe (Maybe (Maybe (Maybe Bool)))`, etc). Each Haskell Functor's destination category is an entire mirror image of **Hask** nested under the functor's type constructor.

So Haskell's `Functor` class is quite a restricted version of the general notion of a category theory functor, and even quite restricted compared to the notion of "an endofunctor on **Hask**". But if we are talking specifically about Haskell Functors, then yes, a function that is the result of `fmap` will always return (and take) values in a "lifted" type.

---

<sup>1</sup> Be aware that "lifting" and "lifted" as applied to things in Haskell have a number of established meanings in different contexts, so don't automatically assume anything else you see talking about "lifted types" means the same thing as in this discussion.

Comment: Thanks. Nice explanation.

Answer (score 1):

What you can call lifting is what the type constructor `Maybe` does to the type `Int` in order to construct the type `Maybe Int`, and what `fmap` does to some function of type `Int -> Int` in order to construct a function of type `Maybe Int -> Maybe Int`.

Comment: So to generalize, an endofunctor always return a lifted type?